# Coded UI Test Builder records similar classes, creating numerous classes in UIMap

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, builder, coded-ui-tests

Is there a way to force Coded UI Test Builder to use it’s already recorded classes?
It creates very similar classes even within single recording session.

E.g. the only difference in URL in two classes generated below.
I’d like to reuse code – no sense to have such duplications. Anything besides manual cleanup?

```
public class UISearchResultsOracleDocument : HtmlDocument
{
    public UISearchResultsOracleDocument(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
        base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
        this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.RedirectingPage] = "False";
        this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.FrameDocument] = "False";
        this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Title] = "Search Results : " + EnterSearchedTextParams.UISearchEditText;
        this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/project/Pages/results.aspx";
        this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.PageUrl] = "http://my.url.com:123/project/Pages/results.aspx?k=Oracle";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Search Results : Oracle");
        #endregion
    }
 // ...
```

}

//And almost duplicate

```
public class UISearchResultsOracleDocument1 : HtmlDocument
{
    public UISearchResultsOracleDocument1(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
        base(searchLimitContainer)
 {
     #region Search Criteria
     this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
     this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.RedirectingPage] = "False";
     this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.FrameDocument] = "False";
     this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.Title] = "Search Results : Oracle";
     this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/project/Pages/results.aspx";
     this.FilterProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.PageUrl] = "http://my.url.com:123/project/Pages/results.aspx?k=Oracle&start1=1";
     this.WindowTitles.Add("Search Results : Oracle");
     #endregion
 }
// ...
}
```

Thus, question is how to eliminate duplication? 
Any hints to decrease number of new classes in UIMap?

Thanks

Yuri

Answer (score 0):

try going thr below links..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/12/18/why-is-coded-ui-test-generated-code-not-a-straight-line-code.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/12/21/understanding-the-code-generated-by-coded-ui-test-part-2.aspx

from above links:

> The guidelines for code generation
>   that we came up with (some based on
>   the feedback received) was -
>
> ```
> Encourage reusability of the test code. This is both for productivity
> ```
>
> and better maintenance.
>       Make customization of code easier for common scenarios like Data
>   Driving.
>       Give full control on the code for advance operation.

You can always hand code the same.but is much more tricker than recording it.